# How to differentiate series $\sum_{n=1}^{100} n(101 - n) \times \log(x - n)$

Tags: derivatives

How to differentiate series $\sum\limits_{n =1}^{100} n(101 - n) \times \log(x - n)$?

I was solving a problem which is mentioned below:

> If $f(x) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{100} (x-n)^{n(101 - n)}$ then find $\dfrac{f(101)}{f'(101)}$.

I took log on both sides of the given function and I am unable to find the derivative of the series.

Can anyone just give me a hint how to differentiate the series as I'm just a beginner to this topic. I would be greatly thankful.

Comment: Since the sum is finite (up to $100$), you can differentiate each term independantly.

Comment: The derivative of $\ln (x-n)$ is $\frac{1}{x-n}$

Comment: @AlanAbraham but it's inside the summation. Doesn't that matter?

Comment: Look at what TheSilverDoe said about differentiating the summation.

Comment: Derivative of a (finite number of terms) sum = sum of the derivatives of each term, whether there are 2 or 120340123 terms in the sum.

Comment: To emphasize, the number of terms must be some static number not related to the variable you are differentiating by.  There is a popular fake proof where people try to perform $\frac{d}{dx}[x^2]$ by saying $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^x x\right] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^x 1 = x$.  That simply is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to the OP for being wary of assuming that $F(x)=\sum f_n(x)$ implies $F'(x)=\sum f_n'(x)$, but for *finite* sums that assumption is indeed justified. Consequently, the derivative of $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{100}n(101-n)\log(x-n)$ is

$$F'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{100}{n(101-n)\over x-n}$$

and so

$$F'(101)=\sum_{n=1}^{100}n={100\cdot101\over2}=5050\quad\text{(Ligget se!)}^*$$

The justification for bringing the derivative inside a finite sum is essentially just mathematical induction on the linearity formula $(f+g)'=f'+g'$.  It's only when you have an *infinite* sum that things get dicey and you have to be careful.

$^*$See [Versions of the Gauss Schoolroom Anecdote](http://bit-player.org/wp-content/extras/gaussfiles/gauss-snippets.html) collected by Brian Hayes.